# Probability and a deck of cards - edit

Tags: probability, statistics

Good Evening,

Thanks to Lulu for input that has lead to this edit.

I want to know what is the mean value of 10 cards picked at random from a deck of 52 with ace being valued at 1.

Maximum Score
13,13,13,13,12,12,12,12,11,11 (122)

Minimum score
1111,2222,33 (18)

Expected Value = 7 (91/13). Mean = 70

What is the probability of picking 10 cards that sum above,below and exactly on the mean.

Value Summary
1
(ace)   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11 (jack)   12 (queen) 13 (king)    91 x 4 suits (364 total)

Comment: Just to be sure, the cards are picked WITHOUT replacement, correct?

Comment: That is correct, once the card is picked the deck reduces by 1.

Comment: The Expected Value of a single card is about  $6.538$.  Expectation is additive, even if the random variables are not independent.  Thus the expectation of $10$ cards is about $65.38$.  More work is needed to get the probabilities (even for a single draw it isn't $50-50$ as there are $6$ values below the mean and $7$ above.).

Comment: Lulu, thank you for the quick response, I had done a brief sample of 100 hands using 66 as the mean, the results came back under 50, over 47 and 66 came 3 times. Is there anywhere were a computer based sample can be created. This would remove any shuffling bias. To hit 66 3 times seems a bit high for actual probability .

Comment: If we change the value of the Jack to 11, Queen to 12 , King to 13. The expected value would become 7.  Can we work out the probability of over under hitting 70 exact?

Comment: As you surmise, that (modified) question is easier as we now have a symmetry.  $P(>70)=P(<70)$.  All you have to do then, is to calculate the probability, $p$, of getting exactly $70$.   Still a bit of a mess, as there are lots of ways to get to a sum of $70$ and they aren't all equally likely.

Comment: My head hurts :) if there are 4 of each card, why is the likelihood of hitting 70 not equal for all combinations?

Comment: Because it is more likely if you skip duplicates.  That is, the combination $\{12,12,12,12,2,2,2,2,7,7\}$ is relatively unlikely compared to, say, $\{2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12\}$.   unless you need an analytic solution, I'd go for a simulation.  To simulate, you just need a random number generator.  choose uniform integers from $1$ to $52% rejecting duplicates.

Comment: How would I go about doing that in excel, the RANDBETWEEN function just picks a number, it will not take into account the many variable combinations such as duplicates

Comment: Well, if you are doing this sort of thing a lot, it's not a bad idea to just write a shuffle program.  Something that generates a random permutation of $\{1,\dots, 52\}$.   The Knuth shuffle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation) is pretty easy to program, even in Excel.  Having this lying around comes in very handy.  Anyway, if you have this, then you can just "shuffle" and take the first ten cards.

Comment: Worth remarking that the Knuth shuffle is sequential.  That is, you generate the first random card, then the second, and so on.  If all you want is $10$ you can just stop at the tenth.

Comment: Using the random function on excel over 10,000 samples x 100 runs , 70 appeared 0.098% of the time.

Comment: Well, can't say that number is shocking but, then, it is hard to have any meaningful intuition.

Comment: the figure comes to between 2 & 3% over 1,300 runs using method in below link... i will have to try to learn how to add the function for Knuth to this data.

Comment: http://kiyototamura.tumblr.com/post/91613880102/generating-a-random-permutation-in-excel